# How do I add advanced options to Magento product page?

Tags: magento, product

First of all, maybe I'd best explain what I want to do:
I'm building a Magento-based site, which is going to sell domain names, webhosting packages, etcetera. Therefor, it should be possible for a visitor to choose what domain should be registered with a package (like: visitor chooses a package, and is then asked to choose a domain name). Most simple option: just use custom product options, where the visitor should enter his domain name.

But, as you might guess, this isn't enough. It does not check the availability of the domain name, and it does not provide a drop-down or something for all available top-domains as well.

I know enough of API's that can handle requests for domain availability, and you can consider that part of the job as 'done', but I really don't know how I would add this functionality to the product page of Magento.

I hope I explained everything clearly, don't hesitate to ask if I forgot some details.

With kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing this part independently of the catalog itself as a standalone module. Then, once you've found the domains that the customer wants, pass them to the cart options for that domain. That way, I think you'd have fewer problems with customers trying sly things with the product options.